# Vanilla javascript select by name

Tags: javascript

So I have this issue where I need to set a value to a checkbox depending on some variables.

The problem is that I encountered the next naming convention on the HTML I'll be working with:

```
<input id="jc_1" type="checkbox" name="jc[1]">
<input id="jc_2" type="checkbox" name="jc[2]">
<input id="jc_3" type="checkbox" name="jc[3]">
<input id="jc_4" type="checkbox" name="jc[4]">
```

To decide which input to select I would normally do:

```
document.getElementsByName('jc')
```

Then loop through all of them and decide which one to check, the problem here is that I don't really know how to handle this situation in these specific conditions.

**I can't use JQuery and I can't change my HTML markup.**

Comment: It's a shame the name is `jc[1]`, any chance you can put `jc[]`? `[]` will give you autonumbering.

Comment: Did not work, I tried that already. If you are talking about changing the HTML names I really can't do that.

Comment: what variables determines a value change? the name?

Comment: What browser versions do you need to support? In reasonably-modern browsers, [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) should do the trick. A [polyfill](https://github.com/termi/CSS_selector_engine) is available for older browsers.

Comment: That would be the name, id or class. I can work with all of those.
For this particular problem I decided to try with name, but if you've got a solution using the id, that would be great as well.

Comment: I'm targeting Firefox  34.0.5 specifically. @PaulRoub

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [begins with attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) with [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
var jcList = document.querySelectorAll("[name^=jc\\[]");
```

Beware though that this could match the following elements:

```
<input id="jc_1" type="checkbox" name="jc[0][0]">
```

Which may not be a problem for your particular requirements.

Comment: Way better than my answer. Kudos.

Comment: Also, as said by a commenter, there is a polyfill available for older browsers.

Comment: @V.Roudge Depends. Your answer will accurately select all `jc[N]` elements, whereas this solution assumes there will never be an N-dimensional array element

Comment: Perfect, this would work correctly for this particular case. Thanks will accept this answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Too bad you can't change the markup.

You could do something like..

```
for(var i = 0; i<numberOfCheckboxes.length; i++){
    document.getElementsByName('jc['+i+']');
}
```

But this is really terrible code. And that's assuming that you know numberOfCheckboxes.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByName()` returns an array (even if it just contains one element. You just need to reference the [0] element in your selected array like this `document.getElementsByName('jc[1]')[0]`

```
document.getElementsByName('jc[1]')[0].setAttribute('checked','checked');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/fb0g1at8/)**